# html table with photo's margin issue on website

Tags: html, css

I'm making this website for school with html5 and css.
I used a table to put some photo's as a galery on my website but there's this margin on the right and i can't get rid of it.
Could anyone help me out?

Comment: We can't help without code. Post a [mcve] in your question please. And see [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the question does not contain much info, best advice is to use Chrome DevTools and inspect the item in question. This way you can find the part of css that creates that extra margin. This does not fix the problem, but you will know the cause.

Click 'inspect' on top of your image to open the tool and then change the css (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/)

You can learn more about Chrome devTools from chrome developer pages at https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/